# spellchecker for actionscript 2 projector?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a AS2 based projector compiled into EXE using mprojector. I need to add spellchecking to the textboxes, is there any spellchecker available for AS2??? I have only found valid solutions for AS3. HELP!!!

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it doesn't appear there is a built-in. Have you considered writing one yourself? It would primarily involve writing a dictionary (either as an array or as an external file), and then having each word entered checked against the dictionary.

I can't exactly walk you through all the steps here, but if you decide to build one, break it down into steps, do what you can, and post questions for the things you can't figure out.

By the by, I obviously don't know your project specs, so this is rather general, but you may want to consider using AS3, if at all possible. There are significant improvements over AS2. So, unless your project absolutely relies on AS2, I'd look into upgrading. It'll make things a lot easier.